# How to write in plpgsql code in plpythonu funtion (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a function written in plpythonu.
I want to add a 2 line code that will be written in plpgsql to this function.

This is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION A(x integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$$
   plpythonu  code...
    ####################
    add some comands in plpgsql 
    ####################
   plpythonu  code...
$$
  LANGUAGE plpythonu VOLATILE
```

How do I do that?
The plpgsql  code is ready I just need to know how to make plpythonu  accept it.

I know I can create a function for the plpgsql  code and call it from python but it seems excessive.

Any ideas?

Comment: A function can only be implemented in a single language. Either PL/pgSQL **or** PL/Python

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I saw there is an option to open a block in different language https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-do.html

Answer (score 0):

In the same way as for clear SQL code - execute (by using DO clause). You can not put plpgsql (as any other pl language) in function by another language.

Comment: but what about DO statments? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-do.html

Comment: I say that plpgsql can be called as plain SQL via execute (as string). I mean than you can not inline code in one language directly in code in another. Probably my English does not allow me to write this correctly.